# Something wrong with my proof on little-o Big-O arithmetics

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, solution-verification

I run into this problem in a web site and it states that the equality below is false. When I try to prove that this is false I end up finding out that it is true. What I wanted to ask you is where I did wrong in the proof below. I dont give up quickly but it's been three days, it started really to put me back into my schedule.
Do you think my proof is false in any step?
Thanks in advance!

[The question screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvLDQ.jpg)

$o(x^n) + o(x^m) = O(x^n), {x \to \infty}, n>m$

$ f(x) = o(x^n) \iff |f(x)| < \epsilon * |x^n| , \forall x \geq N $

$ g(x) = o(x^m) \iff |g(x)| < \epsilon * |x^m| , \forall x \geq M $

$ |f(x)| + |g(x)| \leq \epsilon * (|x^n| + |x^m|) , \forall x \geq \max(M,N) $

$ |f(x) + g(x)| \leq |f(x)| + |g(x)| \leq \epsilon * (|x^n| + |x^m|) , \forall x \geq \max(M,N) $ (triangle inequality)

$ |f(x) + g(x)| \leq \epsilon * (|x^n| + |x^m|) , \forall x \geq \max(M,N) $  (logical result of the statement above)

$ |f(x) + g(x)| \leq \epsilon * (|x^n| + |x^m|) \leq \epsilon * (|x^n| + |x^n|) , \\ \forall x \geq \max(M,N)\ \  (\text{if }\ \  n>m\ \text{ then}\ \  x^n > x^m\ \  if\ \ x\ \to \infty) $

$ |f(x) + g(x)| \leq \epsilon * 2 * |x^n|, \\ \forall x \geq \max(M,N) $ (logical result of the statement above)

$ |f(x) + g(x)| \leq \epsilon'  * |x^n|, \forall x \geq \max(M,N),\ (where\ \epsilon' = 2*\epsilon)$

$ f(x) + g(x) = o(x^n), \forall x \geq \max(M,N) $ (formal definition of little-o)

$ o(x^n) + o(x^m) = o(x^n), \forall x \geq \max(M,N) $ (replace f(x) and g(x) back)

$ o(x^n) + o(x^m) = O(x^n), \forall x \geq \max(M,N) $ (little-o implies big-O)

Comment: Do you have a link to the web site?

Comment: Sure, it's a Calculus and Optimization for Machine Learning MOOC from National Research University of  Higher School of Economics on Coursera. Week2, Practice Quiz #2. I'll add a link to the screenshot to my question. Since it needs either a financial aid or paid, I can't link directly to the quiz section though.

Comment: Makes no sense to me.  I would say both the first and last expressions are incorrect, since $x_m$ hasn't been defined.  I haven't read your argument in complete detail, but glancing over it, it looks correct.  Certainly I agree with your conclusion.  By the way, `$x\to\infty$` comes out as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Since the $x_m$ is presumably a typo (twice!), perhaps there is a typo in choice (c) as well.

Comment: @saulspatz thank you for the tip and your time!

Comment: @DavidK how do you mean?

Comment: My guess is that they are using $O$ to mean "$O$ but not $o$." In my opinion that's a mistake.

Comment: it isn't normal? I mean O does not include o @AndreasBlass

Comment: @H.Can I certainly don't consider it normal to exclude o from O.

Comment: Can you give feedback for my argument also? It's been important for me because I've spent a lot of time on that. Do you see any wrong steps in it? @AndreasBlass

Comment: Your argument is essentially fine, but you should omit the "$\forall x\geq\max(M,N)$" from the last three lines, since the restriction to sufficiently large $x$ is already contained in o and O. A slightly more efficient proof could begin with a fixed value, say $1$, for $\epsilon$. Then you'd get $2$ as your $\epsilon'$, which (though useless for proving o) is enough to establish the O that you want.

Comment: What I meant about the typo in choice (c) was that it might be that there was some false statement that was intended to be given for this choice, but because of an error in transcription or typesetting the statement actually shown there is not the one that was intended. Since the statement was _supposed_ to be false, choice (c) was recorded as the correct choice in the answer key, but due to the error in  transcription or typesetting it is actually a true statement just like all the others.

Comment: Oh okay, so you too say that all the choices are true then? @DavidK

Comment: As they are written, if you change $x_m$ to $x^m$ and make typical interpretations of the notations, they are all true.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that the subscripts are both typographical errors (what a lousy test!) and should actually be superscripts. Secondly, as per the comments it uses a common **abuse of notation** where people write "$f = O(g)$" to mean "$f ∈ O(g)$". I shall just state the **precise** facts:

Take any $m,n∈ℕ$ such that $m<n$.

1. As $x → ∞$, we have $o(x^n)+o(x^m) ⊆ o(x^n)+o(x^n) ⊆ o(x^n) ⊆ O(x^n)$, where the 2nd and 3rd steps are obvious and the 1st is because eventually $x > 1$ and so $x^m ≤ x^n$. (I will leave you to try the actual $ε,δ$-proof.)
2. As $x → ∞$, we have $o(x^n) ⊆ o(x^n)+o(x^m)$, and so by fact 1 we have $o(x^n)+o(x^m) = o(x^n)$.
3. As $x →∞$, we have $o(x^n)+o(x^m) = o(x^n) ≠ O(x^n)$ because $x^n ∈ O(x^n)$ but $x^n ∉ o(x^n)$.

People who abuse notation write $o(x^n)+o(x^m) = O(x^n)$, which is wrong because it contradicts the third fact above.

As for your proof attempt, you neither defined not quantified $ε$, so it is wrong. Look at the [**actual formal definitions**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations) of the asymptotic notations; they do not look like yours.

Comment: Thank you for that, understand that. Can you also give feedback for my argument? Its errors etc?

Comment: Part (d) is about $x\to 0$, not $x\to\infty$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Oops. Then it is possible that they are not using the abuse of notation and asking for actual equality, which would make (3) the only false statement (assuming $m,n$ are natural).

Comment: @H.Can: As per my last comment, since I misread (d), the only way to preserve the correctness of the question is to assume they mean equality of the asymptotic classes. Only you can tell us whether they use the common abuse of notation or not. As for your proof attempt, it's really quite messy. It's better to directly manipulate: $o(x^n)+o(x^m) ∈ O(x^n)+O(x^m) ⊆ O(x^n)+O(x^n) ⊆ O(x^n)$.

Comment: @H.Can: And there are plenty of missing quantifiers in your proof attempt, so I wouldn't consider it as correct.

Comment: What's the difference between f(x) = o(g(x)) and f(x) $ \in $ o(g(x))? If x goes to a finite number we use the former one whereas it goes to infinity we use the latter one?

Comment: @H.Can: Equality is supposed to be symmetric. As $x → ∞$ we have $O(x) ⊆ O(x^2)$ but $O(x^2) \not⊆ O(x)$. So why should you use "$=$"? It is technically simply wrong.

Comment: Anyway, you need to clarify whether they are using the abuse of notation or not. If they are not, then (c) is false. If they are, then (c) is true, but your proof is not (in my judgement) correct. An expert can easily 'see' a corrected version of your proof, but that does not mean you have a fully correct proof. After you clarify, I will either fix my answer or delete it, since you have now seen my responses in the comments.

Comment: I dont think they are abusing the notation because they show it like that throughout the course. It'd be great if you edit your answer by showing how (c) is false, the steps etc. Thank you for your time. @user21820

Comment: @H.Can: If they always use "$=$" instead of "$∈,⊆$", then that means they are *always* abusing notation. I already explained in my above comment why it is an abuse of notation. Even if many people abuse the notation constantly, it does not imply that it is correct or beneficial, just as many people smoke tobacco.

Comment: I'm a computer engineer, so I unfortunately don't know rigorously quantifier based math proofs. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @H.Can: I [replied to that in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55785815#55785815). All I can guarantee you is that if you choose to learn basic FOL (first-order logic), I can help you with that, and after that you will be able to understand all fully rigorous mathematical proofs completely, and be able to easily generate them as well (for simple theorems like this one). It *will* take some effort, but it is necessary if you want to truly grasp mathematics.